# Number validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, function

```
$('#empcontact').blur(function(){
        var stri = $('#empcontact').val();//the input element
        var numbers = "0123456789";
        var flag = false;
        for(var x=0;x<stri.length;x++){
            var ch = stri.charAt(x);
            var n = numbers.indexOf(ch);
            if(n === -1){//why does it always resolve to true            
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        if(flag){
            alert("Not a number");
            $('#empcontact').val(" ");
            $('#empcontact').focus();
        }
});
```

I don't know why it always resolves to true even when numbers are passed also when characters are passed.

Comment: n === 1, does not make sense

Comment: `numbers` needs to be an **array** to use `.indexOf`. "n === -1" will never make sense. "===" should only be used for '0' and '1'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use [$.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/),like:

```
var stri = $('#empcontact').val();
console.log( $.isNumeric( stri ) ); //returns true if is number
```

or

```
var stri = $('#empcontact').val();
console.log(typeof stri === 'number' && isFinite(stri) ); //returns true if number
```

or only integers

```
var intsOnly = /^\d+$/,
    stri = $('#empcontact').val();
if(intsOnly.test(stri)) {
   alert('its valid');   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A javascript solution would be

```
if(isNaN(parseInt('a'))){ // replace 'a' with your variable
    flag = true;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for number via this:

```
 function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
 }
```

OR

```
function isNumber(n){
  return (parseFloat(n) == n);
}
```

Because `IsNumeric` will fail in the following cases:

```
IsNumeric(' ') == true;
IsNumeric('\t\t') == true;
IsNumeric('\n\r') == true;

IsNumeric(-1) == false;
IsNumeric(0) == false;
IsNumeric(1.1) == false;
IsNumeric(8e5) == false;
```

Or If you want to use Regexp for this, there are many Regexp available for this:

```
/^[0-9]+$/

/^\d*$/

[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good regex situation to me, use:

```
if(stri.match(/^[0-9]*$/)){
    alert("numeric!");
    // do whatever else...
}
```

$.isNumeric will allow crazy semi-numeric stuff like `0xFF` and `2e5`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Number Validation Plugin that is a plugin for jQuery that performs validation of an HTML input number type.

https://github.com/prednaxela/jquery.numbervalidation

Comment: An example of how to use the plugin would be helpful. Your answer as it stands is borderline "Link Only" which is against SO's guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

**Number Validation**

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 99 && charCode != 118 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```